# Insert JSON into MongoDb directly from PHP

Tags: php, json, mongodb

I have an Android application which sends `json` data to PHP script.
The PHP script have to save the data into MongoDB.

When I insert the data, MongoDB treat this data as a string.

```
$conn = new Mongo('mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017');

// access database
$db = $conn->Data;

// access collection
$collection = $db->Collection;
$collection->insert($myjson)
```

How can I say to MongoDB PHP driver that it is already a `json` document?

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The PHP MongDB Driver accepts arrays for inserts and queries (see here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mongo.queries.php)

So you need to convert your JSON to an array.

Luckily, in general this is quite easy ... here is a snippet from a longer piece of code (see this [article](http://learnmongo.com/posts/mongodb-php-twitter-part-1/)) to insert JSON data from the Twitter API into an array, then into MongoDB:

```
// Convert JSON to a PHP array
$usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline);

// Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
   $collection->insert($item);
}
```

Note the **[json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** function can convert to an array by passing true as the second parameter.

Comment: How would you handle inserting native Mongo data types like MongoDate?

Answer (score 5):

Here's a tip for others who want to do this, but want to update records rather than insert new ones. In order to get Justin's approach to work, I had to make sure that I convert the _id object for each item to a MongoId:

```
// Convert JSON to a PHP array
$usertimeline = json_decode($usertimeline);

// Loop array and create seperate documents for each tweet
foreach ($usertimeline as $id => $item) {
   $mongo_id = new MongoId($id);
   $item->_id = $mongo_id;
   $collection->update(array('_id' => $mongo_id), $item);
}
```

Comment: Small update if someone finds this issue in 2024, use MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID

Answer (score 1):

As MongoDB PHP library supports conversion from JSON to BSON and BSON to PHP Std Class Object, You can follow simple steps.

```
    //Convert Row (Document) to json
    $json_row = json_encode($row);

    //Convert JSON to BSON
    $bson = \MongoDB\BSON\fromJSON($json_row);

    //Convert BSON to PHP Std Class object
    $row = \MongoDB\BSON\toPHP($bson);


    // Insert Record to Document
    $collection->insertOne($row);
```

You can get full MongoDB database backup and restore script from here
https://github.com/sulochanatutorials/php-mongodb-backup-restore

Comment: Please [edit] your answer to include an explanation of how this works and why it is of solution to the problem described in the question. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB uses BSON not JSON so you need to re-encode anyways. Also, I remember talking to kchodorow about this and the raw interface was not exposed then (been half a year at least) and I doubt it is now so even if you manage to get BSON data from somewhere , you can't avoid the de/encode.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATE 2021 WITH PHP 7 DRIVER:**

Lets say your json string is

```
$myjson = {"name":"foo", "age":30}
```

First decode it with PHP [json_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php). Which returns an array.

```
$myarraydata = json_decode($myjson)
```

Now you can directly insert it into mongoDB

```
$bulk = new MongoDB\Driver\BulkWrite(['ordered' => true]);
$bulk->insert($myarraydata);
$writeConcern = new MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern(MongoDB\Driver\WriteConcern::MAJORITY, 1000);
$result = $connection->executeBulkWrite('dbname.collection_name', $bulk, $writeConcern);
```

Check bulk operation official documentation [here](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.mongodb-driver-bulkwrite.php).